# How to fill the NA values based on another column in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe in python where I want to fill the NA values based on another column

| Name | Class |
| --- | --- |
| AB | Sixth |
| MN | Ninth |
| QR | NaN |
| AB | NaN |
| MN | Ninth |
| TS | Second |
| AB | Sixth |
| TS | NaN |
| MN | NaN |
| NaN | NaN |
| QR | First |
| TS | Second |
| NaN | Sixth |
| NaN | Ninth |
| NaN | First |

I want to fill the NA values for both the cols 
i.e. 
**If the name is AB then the class should be Sixth and vice versa

If the name is QR then the class should be First and vice versa**
So on and so forth...
Also if both the columns have NULL fields then It will remain NULL (nothing will change as later I will fill those NA fields with the mode).  
Note: The actual problem is different however It requires the same logic as I cannot post that problem here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I've understood you correctly, you can create mapping dictionary and use it in `.map` to fill `NaN` values:

```py
mapping = df.dropna().drop_duplicates().set_index("Name")["Class"].to_dict()
inv_mapping = {v: k for k, v in mapping.items()}

df.loc[df["Name"].isna(), "Name"] = df.loc[df["Name"].isna(), "Class"].map(
    inv_mapping
)
df.loc[df["Class"].isna(), "Class"] = df.loc[df["Class"].isna(), "Name"].map(
    mapping
)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   Name   Class
0    AB   Sixth
1    MN   Ninth
2    QR   First
3    AB   Sixth
4    MN   Ninth
5    TS  Second
6    AB   Sixth
7    TS  Second
8    MN   Ninth
9   NaN     NaN
10   QR   First
11   TS  Second
12   AB   Sixth
13   MN   Ninth
14   QR   First
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Andrej Kesely. It worked. I was also using the mapping but  had made a mistake in that. 
Thanks again for explaining in such a simple way